# How to use link_to to go to a subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to

I am having trouble using link_to to go to my posts/index page. I have the following link_to:

```
<%= link_to('NEWS', posts_path(subdomain:"news"),:class=>'navtext',:style=>"color:#bfbebc!important;")  %>
```

My routes:

```
  resources :posts , constraints: { subdomain: 'news' }
```

When I am at http://news.lvh.me:3000/posts (the actual page the link_to refers to) the link works, however when I place in on any other page (for example, the root_path) it does not work. I get the `No route matches [GET] "/posts"` error which I think means that the subdomain is not passed in my link_to. Any ideas on how I can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `posts_url`, instead of `posts_path`.

It works fine on my project even without `(subdomain:"news")`. Just use `posts_url` directly.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else works you could just skip the helper altogether:

```
<%= link_to('NEWS', subdomain_link,:class=>'navtext',:style=>"color:#bfbebc!important;")  %>
```

To make it work in both development and production you could write a helper method in `application_helper.rb`:

```
def subdomain_link
  Rails.env.development? ? '//whatever.localhost:3000' : '//news.whatever.com'
end
```

To go even further, you could configure `subdomain_link` to accept a string as an argument and interpolate that into the domain string. Another approach would be to configure a `config` variable in `config/environments/development.rb` and `config/environments/production.rb`.

Comment: This is for production right? I was hoping for something that would work for both local and prod. Thanks though :)